# How to apply Rouché's Theorem for $p(z)=5z^6-10z^4+z+4$. Does Rouché's Theorem have any limatation?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is how to apply Rouché's Theorem for $p(z)=5z^6-10z^4+z+4$. Does Rouché's Theorem have any limatation? 
I find for some problems, it is easy to find $f(z)$ and $g(z)$. But for some problems, sometimes not quite easy.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Of course the theorem has limitations, what do you mean by that?

Comment: In what domain do you want to use Rouche's theorem ?

Comment: The problem is $p(z)=5z^6−10z^4+z+4$, I want to use Rouche's theorem in the unit circle centred at origin. To find how many roots in this unit circle.

Comment: That has the problem that $f(1)=0$ so that there is no $g$ with $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ for all points $z$ on the unit circle.

Comment: And also $$p(z)=(z-1)\Bigl(5(z+1)(z^2+\sqrt3 z+1)(z^2-\sqrt3 z+1)+1\Bigr)$$ which is in the second factor a product with lots of roots on the unit circle plus a small number. This prevents the standard estimates from working.